# Can not access collection object's value in erb file - has_many relationship - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, has-many

In my application, there are two classes , which have '**has_many**' relationship.
And from that design, I can fetch object from my controller(*_controler.rb) and can pass successfully to my view (*.html.erb)

But on view part(*.html.erb) i can not access object's collection class...

I got following exception:

```
ActionView::TemplateError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.inject) on line #31 of app/views/student/_populate.html.erb:
```

Model Classes:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :Subject, :class_name=>"Subject"

    attr_accessible :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, 

    self.table_name="students"
    set_primary_key :id

    blahblah
end

class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :Student, :foreign_key=>'student_id'

    attr_accessible :student_id, :name

    self.table_name="subjects"

    blahblah
end
```

Controller:

```
class StudentController < ApplicationController

    require "student.rb"

    def populate
        @pos=0

        filter_query = ''
        if !params[:firstName].blank?
            filter_query +=" first_name='" + params[:firstName].to_s + "' and"
        end

        if filter_query !=''
            filter_query= filter_query[0..filter_query.length-4]
            @stuData= Student.find(:all, :conditions=>filter_query)
        end

    end
```

View:

populate.html.erb

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="heading" style="float:left;width:900px;">    
        <% form_tag(:controller=>"student", :action=>"populate") do %>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td width="10"> <label> First Name:</label> </td>
                    <td width="40"> <%= text_field_tag('firstName') %> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <input name="submitFormName" class="form_submit" type="submit" value="Search" />

        <% end %>

        <div height="10">&nbsp;</div>

    </div> 
</div>

<div class="students" style="float:left;width:1330px;">

    <% if !@stuData.blank? %>
        size = <%= @stuData.size %>
        <% if !@stuData.nil? %>
            <%= render :partial=>'populate' , :locals=>{:stuData => @stuData} %>
        <% end %>
    <% else %>
        <div>Not found...</div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

_populate.html.erb

```
<div style="overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:scroll;">              
    <table >
      <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Middle Name </th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Subject Name</th>
      </thead>    
      <% stuData.each do |item| %>
      <tr>
        <td id="studentId"> <%= item.id %> </td>
        <td id="firstNameId"> <%= item.promotion_code %> </td>
        <td id="middleNameId"> &nbsp; </td>
        <td id="lastNameId"> &nbsp; </td>
        <td id="cityId">
          <% @var1 = item.Subject %>
          <% if @var1.nil? %>
            <% @var1.each do |pc| %>
              <%= pc.name %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
```

I have crossed check on console:

```
@student = Student.find(144)
=> #<Student id: 4, first_name: "ABC", middle_name: "DEF", last_name: "GHI">
>> 
?> @isNullCheck = @student.Subject.nil?
=> false
>> 
?> @subList = @student.Subject
=> [#<Subject id: 5, student_id: 4, name: "Maths">, #<Subject id: 6, student_id: 4, name: "English"> ]
>> 
?> @StuSub1 = @student.Subject[0]
=> #<Subject id: 5, student_id: 4, name: "Maths">
>> 
?> @StuSub2 = @student.Subject[1]
=> #<Subject id: 6, student_id: 4, name: "English">
==
?> @StuSub3 = @student.Subject[2]
=> nil
>> 
>> @StuSubValue1 = @student.Subject[0].value
=> Maths
>> 
>> @StuSubValue2 = @student.Subject[0].value
=> English
>>
```

Problem:
When i will search any student details from the page(populate.html.erb), my controller will fetch the data and passed the object (@stuData) to the template(_populate.html.erb).

Template(_populate.html.erb) can print student's data.
But can not print student's subject's name. (As student has many subjects)

I have googled many things....

i think there is nothing wrong in model's design and controller part.... 
but i think problem might be with

- page rendering or
- local parameters passing to template or
- collection parameter passing to template...

but i am not sure....

can any one help me in this???

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I have no idea that ruby stuff is so much strict about singular-plural and case sensitivity...

Answer (score 1):

Your relationships are set up incorrectly. Variable names cannot begin with a capital letter. [This article](http://zetcode.com/lang/rubytutorial/variables/) may help.

Set them up without using capitals and use plurals instead - like so:

`has_many :subjects` and `belongs_to :student`

and make sure you propagate changes through your views

Comment: after restart of the server... same problem starts... so i think it is not the problem....

Comment: are you saying that the problem appeared to be fixed when you made these changes but then it reappeared after a server restart?

Comment: Yes....exactly. And one more strange thing happens is: Whenever i start my server, at that time for the first request, it retrieves collection and works totally well... but from the second request...i got null pointer exception...

Comment: so i have doubt that... there is something problematic in my response handling / rendring mechanism... ?  I may miss something which may be a basic/important point while response/page handling/rendering....

Comment: In my case...  search page and search result page is the same. does this create this problem??

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please modify your post to include the entire error relating to this 'null pointer exception' and the accompanying stack trace. Also, what do you mean by 'search and search results' - I see only a 'populate' method on your controller.